# Cannot update a single item (object) in a List C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, updates

I have a list of objects:

```
List<NPortfolio> Portfolios = new List<NPortfolio>();
Portfolios.Add(new NPortfolio(1, "1", emptyPositions));
Portfolios.Add(new NPortfolio(2, "2", emptyPositions));
```

Now i want to call a Method on the object that modifies its properties:

```
Portfolios[0].UpdatePositions(db.GetPortfolio(1, Today));
```

The method is this:

```
public void UpdatePositions(Dictionary<string, double> valuepairs)
    {
        foreach (var k in this.positions.Keys.ToList())
        {
            if (valuepairs.ContainsKey(k))
                this.positions[k] = valuepairs[k];
        }
    }
```

This works, but the problem is that when I try to update just the first item of the list:

```
Portfolios[0].UpdatePositions(db.GetPortfolio(1, Today));
```

ALL ITEMS OF THE LIST ARE UPDATED!!!
I cannot find why all items are updated and not only item 0.
Please help this is really an headache

many thanks

class definition:

```
public class NPortfolio
{
    public string p_id { get; set; }
    public int p_nr { get; set; }
    private Dictionary<string, double> positions;
    public NPortfolio(int nr, string id, Dictionary<string, double> pos)
    {
        p_nr = nr;
        p_id = id;
        positions = pos;
    }

    public void UpdatePositions(Dictionary<string, double> valuepairs)
    {
        foreach (var k in this.positions.Keys.ToList())
        {
            if (valuepairs.ContainsKey(k))
                this.positions[k] = valuepairs[k];
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<string, double> getPositions()
    {
            return positions;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the class definition for `NPortfolio`?

Comment: Do you use a static variable for positions?

Comment: Do they all share the same `Dictionary` instance? Also the `ContainsKey` makes no sense to me.

Comment: How do you populate the list?  Are you adding the same reference multiple times?

Comment: how do you fill the Portfolios collection ? what does db.GetPortfolio(1, Today) do ? Why do you do all your operations on 1 row ? - Portfolios[0].UpdatePositions(db.GetPortfolio(1, Today));   You should do it Nportfolio item = Portfolios[i];  then use item.UpdatePosition(...);

Comment: If I do it i 2 steps: Nportfolio item = Portfolios[i]; then use item.UpdatePosition(...); same issue, the entire list ist updated.

Comment: You need to show us how you are populating the dictionary you are passing in to `pos` the problem is most likely there.

Comment: Don't put code in comments, delete those comments and update your question.

Comment: edit your post don't add it as a comment please

Comment: I'll expand on what @ScottChamberlain is saying by suggesting that you create a new dictionary inside you constructor and then populate it with the entries in the `pos` argument that is passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from this

```
Portfolios.Add(new NPortfolio(1, "1", emptyPositions));
Portfolios.Add(new NPortfolio(2, "2", emptyPositions));
```

You are passing the same dictionary to both classes, so if you modify one of the classes you modify both instances.

You must create a new dictionary inside the constructor of `NPortfolio` so each class has a unique copy.

```
public NPortfolio(int nr, string id, Dictionary<string, double> pos)
{
    p_nr = nr;
    p_id = id;
    positions = new Dictionary<string, double>(pos);
}
```

This will make a [shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy) of the dictionary and should solve your issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the same dictionary into your objects.  So when you update it in one you end up seeing the changes in the other.  You should create a new dictionary inside your constructor and populate it with the values passed in.

```
public NPortfolio(int nr, string id, Dictionary<string, double> pos)
{
    p_nr = nr;
    p_id = id;
    positions = new Dictionary<string, double>(pos);
}
```